# How to recreate views without restart activity?

Tags: android

So I got a custom spinner which is setup as needed when activity starts. It shows default value and it is closed by default. Then there are several scenarios for each item in that spinner. But I need to reset everything on the screen in case of error dialog appear. So if error appears my activity need to looks like it is just created from scratch?

Comment: "I got a custom spinner which is setup as needed when activity starts" couldn't you just extract this to a method and call it when your dialog appears ?

Comment: Would even recreate views, but just reset them to their initial state.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer in the comment. You can extract the spinner to a method and call the method as and when you like. No need to start the spinner with the activity.

Comment: the answer is here for me is `this.recreate()` because i need just to restart EVERYTHING not only spinner